# Unable to adjust sound volume

Tags: 13.04, sound

After a reboot, im suddenly unable to adjust the volume. I have tried adjusting it trough the panel shortcut, the Ubuntu "Sound", trough pulseaudio and trough the hardware keys.

Before when I had problems like this, I used to use the amixer. But this app does not seem to be awailable in the repos anymore :\

The laptop is a system76 Gazelle professional

Any Ideas?

Comment: try typing alsamixer in terminal. Alsamixer is available in Ubuntu Software Center and Synaptic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue after pulseaudio update.

Try remove pulse configs:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ rm -r ~/.config/pulse/
```

After restart the system.